# using if statement in sql function

Tags: sql-server

i have a code like this

```
create function factfind(@num integer) 
returns integer 
as
begin
if   (@num=1) then
return 1;
else
return(@num*factfind(@num-1));
end if;
end
```

errors  was  that,
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure factfind, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure factfind, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure factfind, Line 8
'factfind' is not a recognized built-in function name.

please help me friends.

Answer (score 9):

```
...
begin
    return ( CASE
                WHEN @num=1 THEN 1
                ELSE @num * dbo.factfind(@num-1)
             END
        );
end
```

Edit: needs to be `dbo.factfind` because scalar udfs must be schema qualified

Comment: Doesn't a CASE statement require an 'END'?

Answer (score 5):

Execute this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fakultät(@n DECIMAL(38,0))
RETURNS DECIMAL(38,0)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @tmp DECIMAL(38,0)
    IF (@n <= 1)
        SELECT @tmp = 1
 ELSE
  SELECT @tmp = @n * dbo.fakultät(@n - 1)
 RETURN @tmp
END
```

or:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Factorial ( @iNumber int )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @i  int

    IF @iNumber <= 1
        SET @i = 1
    ELSE
        SET @i = @iNumber * dbo.Factorial( @iNumber - 1 )
RETURN (@i)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is in part the syntax of the if statement in TSQL, the right thing to do is:

```
create function factfind(@num integer) 
returns integer 
as 
begin 
  declare @Result int
  set @Result = 1  
  if (@num>1) 
    set @Result = @num * dbo.factfind(@num-1);
  return @Result
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't you include an `ELSE` in there since you are returning twice?

Comment: the function should return a Decimal (38.0) because the results are quite large and can not be contained in an integer from 12!